# Event receiver not binding to Content Type

Tags: content-type, event-receivers

I am unable to attach an event receiver to my custom content type. If I change the inherits property of the content type to `false` , then the content type is not visible after deployment. I change the inherits property of the content type to `true` then the `<XMLDocuments>` tag is getting ignored. Please help me solve this issue.

The Elements.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01008812D4663E574A9DB3147C3277B026A4"
               Name="DeclarativeCT2"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="My Content Type"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{FF878E1C-9C79-485A-B252-193C0EBB4F2D}" 
                Name="CreatedFromXML" DisplayName="Created From XML" 
                ReadOnly="FALSE" 
                Required="TRUE" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
        <Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
          <Receiver>
            <Name>EventReceiverForCTItemUpdating</Name>
            <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
            <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
            <Class>$SharePoint.Type.c2237798-87e9-483b-bb17-1b3d4715fed2.FullName$</Class>
            <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
          </Receiver>
        </Receivers>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
  <Field ID="{FF878E1C-9C79-485A-B252-193C0EBB4F2D}" 
         Name="CreatedFromXML" 
         DisplayName="Created From XML" 
         Type="Text" 
         Required="FALSE" Group="Custom Columns" />
</Elements>
```

The C# code for event receiver is :

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;

namespace DeclarativeCT1
{
    [Guid("C2237798-87E9-483B-BB17-1B3D4715FED2")]
    public class EventReceiverForCT : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

        public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            string customFieldValue = properties.ListItem[new Guid("FF878E1C-9C79-485A-B252-193C0EBB4F2D")].ToString();
            if (customFieldValue.Equals("Fish", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "No Fish in text please";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is screenshot of my project :

[image]

Below is the script i used to check for event receivers
[image]

Comment: How do you know for sure the ER is not attached? Maybe an error is raised in the code of your ER, and you *think* it does not run, whil it actually starts and fails immediately (like `properties.ListItem[new Guid("FF878E1C-9C79-485A-B252...` being `null`.

Comment: @Evariste I have added screenshot of the script I wrote to check the event receivers. The count is zero.

Comment: @Evariste you are actually correct. The event receiver is working. I was just checking the output of the script I wrote. It is misleading. Can anyone explain why the script is misleading ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have bound correct <Class> path in declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ER may be attached, and an error is raised in the code of your ER; you think it does not run, while it actually starts and fails immediately (like at `properties.ListItem[new Guid("FF878E1C-...` being `null`).

Your `$ct.EventReceivers.Count` may not report the ER accordingly since it's registered declaratively (via a feature artefact/XML file).

In such scenarios, I highly prefer an imperative approach, i.e. attaching the ER from C# code in the feature receiver. That way you do control exactly what happens (easier feature upgrade + easier debugging + more control over options + easier to be understood for a developer...).

Comment: "Your $ct.EventReceivers.Count may not report the ER accordingly since it's registered declaratively (via a feature artefact/XML file)." I think the Count parameter should return the count of the registered event recievers, regardless of the type of registration (programmatically or declaratively).